# How Do I Get JavaScript Code Completion (Intellisense) in JXA File in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-automation

It is great that this extension provides us with the ability to code, compile, and run JXA files:
[AppleScript & JXA for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idleberg.applescript)

Unfortunately, JavaScript code completion is not active for a JXA file, even though JXA uses core JavaScript.  Is there some way to enable it for JXA?

I am brand new to VSC, so if you can, please provide detailed instructions.

Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @jim70 -- see the answer I just posted.

Comment: are you referring to an answer here on Stackoverflow or elsewhere? Thanks.

Comment: The powers-that-be in this forum did not like that I provide an excellent answer, but did so via a link to long, extensive article.  Thus, they DELETED my answer.  So, everyone else will suffer because those who want to know the answer are denied it.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> or click the language name in the bottom-right corner. Then change the language currently associated with the file.

I expect there's a setting somewhere to do this generally, but I haven't found one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but won't that break the JXA feature that compiles and runs a JXA script?  Can the JavaScript code completion be added to the JXA extension?

Comment: @JMichaelTX Unfortunately, yes. But short of writing an extension or having more knowledge of the program than I do, there's not a lot you can do about that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
 "files.associations": {
    "*.jxa": "javascript",
    "*.applescript": "javascript"
  },
```

and any other file extensions you use.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language

Comment: Can you please provide details as to how to change/set the file associations in VSC?

Comment: What I wrote in my answer goes into your settings.json and then hopefully you will get javascript syntax completion and theme colors in your `.jxa` files.